# C# - Capture event on multiple dynamically created user controls

Tags: c#, events, controls

I have a User Control which contains 4 labels. 
I populate a panel dynamically with multiple copies of this user control (one for each entry in a database). 
I want to capture a click event on any one of the user controls and grab the id associated with it.

The is the code contained within my user control:

```
public partial class TeamVsTeam: UserControl
{
    public TeamVsTeam()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public int idHomeTeam { get; set; }
    public int idAwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Within my application, I populate a panel with multiple controls like this:

```
TeamVsTeam.TeamVsTeam[] teamLabel = new TeamVsTeam.TeamVsTeam[n];

for (int i = 0; i < m_fixtures.lstTeams.Count; i++)
{
    teamLabel[i] = new TeamVsTeam.TeamVsTeam();

    teamLabel[i].eventID = m_fixtures.lstTeams[i].idEvent;

    teamLabel[i].lblHome.Text = m_fixtures.lstTeams[i].homeTeam.ToString();
    teamLabel[i].lblAway.Text = m_fixtures.lstTeams[i].awayTeam.ToString();

    teamLabel[i].Clicked += new EventHandler(Fixture_Click);

   //Location
    teamLabel[i].Top = 80 * i;
    teamLabel[i].Parent = panel1;
}
```

Is anyone able to suggest some code which I can use to capture the click event (anywhere on the user control) and obtain the `eventID`, `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` from the control which was clicked?

```
    public void Fixture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = ((TeamVsTeam.TeamVsTeam)sender);
        int ID = ctrl.eventID;
        MessageBox.Show(ID.ToString());
    }
```

**EDIT**
I've updated the above code to show what I'm now working with, however, it's not completely solved things for me.

Here's an example of a fully populated user control (3 labels and 2 picture boxes)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tidlarzfoy6j2u/2015-09-30%2015_48_35-Super-6.jpg?dl=0

If I click on any of the light grey background, the click event is triggered and I can grab the fixture eventID. But the event is not triggered if I click on any of the labels or picture boxes. 
I still need to capture the fixture eventID, regardless of what part of the control is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to get data from `sender` after type cast

```
public void Fixture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var ctrl = ((TeamVsTeam.TeamVsTeam)sender);
     int ID = ctrl.eventID;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I was after.
Although the Fixture_Click event isn't actually being triggered when I click on a control. Have I missed something else out?

Comment: @NickRoberts, is `Fixture_Click` in `TeamVsTeam` triggered?

Comment: Ah, I just removed the public void Fixture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) section from within the user control itself and has done the trick. 
Again, thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, this has created one more question. I've updated the original question with my new code...

Comment: @NickRoberts, possible fix: change `TeamVsTeam` .ctor a bit to raise `Click` event after click on child controls:  `InitializeComponent();  label1.Click += (s, e) => OnClick(e); pictureBox1.Click += (s, e) => OnClick(e); /*etc*/`; or `InitializeComponent(); foreach (Control c in Controls) c.Click += (s, e) => OnClick(e);`

Comment: Genius. Worked perfectly. Thanks (again!)